# Programming a Monte carlo simulation using Clojure

Tags: clojure, lisp

The Monte Carlo method for estimating the value of π uses a random number generator to simulate the throwing of darts onto a dart board. In this program, you will simulate a large number of dart throws, and through geometric probability, estimate the value of π based on your empirical results.
Suppose we draw a circle of radius 1 with center at the origin (0, 0). One quarter of that circle lies in the
  rst quadrant  of the Cartesian coordinate plane, where x and y coordinates are both non-negative. The
area of our circle is πr2 = π · (1)2 = π, and so the area of the quarter of the circle in the  rst quadrant
is π . We will  throw  darts at this quarter-circle by randomly generating two coordinates for each dart in 4
the interval [0, 1]; the area where darts might land forms a square of side length 1 and total area 1. The probability that a dart will land inside the quarter circle is found by dividing the area of the target area ( π )
4
by the area of the possible landing area (1). If we  throw  a large number of darts at our board and count the number that land inside the quarter-circle, we can estimate the value of π and thus also π. (Assuming
4
our random number generator is truly random, of course.)

You will program a Monte Carlo simulation in Clojure by implementing the following functions:

1. coord - takes no arguments and returns a list of two randomly generated coordinates in the interval of [0, 1]. See rand and list.
2. throw-darts - takes a single argument n representing how many darts to throw, then generates a list of coordinates of length n. Use repeatedly to generate an in nite sequence of coord calls; use take on the result to take the  rst n results.
3. is-hit? - takes a list containing one dart's coordinates and returns whether that dart falls inside our quarter-circle. Hint: calculate the distance from the origin to the dart's coordinates, and decide if that distance means the dart lands inside or outside the quarter-circle.

I answered the first question:

```
(defun coord () (let ((lst ()))
(dotimes (i 2)
(setf lst (cons (random 2) lst)))
lst))
```

but need help for the two others.

Comment: Just to be clear, is this supposed to be Clojure or Common Lisp? The question says Clojure, but the code looks like CL.

Comment: It is supposed to be Clojure, but I tried it with Lisp since I'm more familiar with Lisp than Clojure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Comment**

This looks like homework, so I'll just add to the hints, assuming you are working in Clojure.

1. Clojure has vector literals, for example `[1 2 "Buckle my shoe"]`, 
   that are easier to use than lists.
2. Use `repeatedly` to generate a sequence of calls to a
   (side-effecting) function. The function you want is `rand`.
3. You need only sum the squares of the co-ordinates. This gives the
   square of the distance, which is <= 1 only if the distance is so.

Your final function should `filter` the hits and `count` them. The proportion of this to the total number estimates pi / 4. You should convert it from a rational to a `double`.

Comment: No, it is not a homework. It is one of other problems that we have to prepare for the exams. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: OK. I've added another clojure hint.I was surprised how inaccurate this turned out to be - even with a million throws, I get only two or three reliable decimal places.